# Using PrestoDB as RDBMS

Tags: oracle, jdbc, presto, presto-jdbc

I'm currently working on a project connecting prestoDB to our DBtool to extract and load different types of data from different sources(json index from elasticsearch, json record from kafka etc).

it works on a DBeaver with a jdbc, however, our DBtool does not allow the connection without a username and password.

Is there any way to create an user and password in prestoDB that we could use like Oracle or MariaDB account connection

Comment: What is the tool that you are using ? Share some references of it?

Comment: we are currently using our own in house software so its hard to provide any reference